# Weblogic multiple domains don't start simultaneosly

Tags: weblogic

I have created 2 domains test1 and test2 in weblogic server and I am using 2 eclipse and add weblogic server in each eclipse with different domain. Eclipse 1 instance has weblogic server with domain test1 and Eclipse 2 instance has weblogic server with domain test2. When I start any instance of weblogic server say test1, I can't start the other instance i.e. test2. Is it possible to start both domain at same port or different port?

WebLogic server version : 10.3.3

Answer (score 2):

The default Weblogic port is 7001. It's highly likely that both of your domains/admin servers are attempting to run on the same port if you didn't attempt to change it.

There are a few different ways you can fix this problem but the easiest is to edit:

`<domain test2 home>/config/config.xml`

And change the following line:

`<server> <name>Test2</name> <listen-port>7001</listen-port>`

Update the listen port for your second server to be something other than 7001. You can also verify if this is the actual problem by checking the log file after trying to start the server. You will have binding socket in use exceptions. The log file will be in:

`<domain test2 home>/servers/<server name>/logs`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming default setup, there are two ports that need to be different.

1. the default port.
   It's defined under `<listen-port>`  in `<DOMAIN_HOME>/config/config.xml`,
2. `DEBUG_PORT` in `<DOMAIN_HOME>/bin/setDomainEnv.sh` (or `.cmd` for Windows).

Make sure they are different in both domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 servers sharing same port on same machine. What stops you from changing admin server port of one of the domains.

Try to have something like below and see if the issue is sorted out

```
<server>
    <name>AdminServer</name>
    <listen-port>8001</listen-port>
```